# How to modify the values of a plot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am working with time-series data (shared [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kQHScTTGUUpI9f-0IrOA1me-4r5g7BcK)).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protocols = {}

types = {"data1": "data1.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] 
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }

    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    plt.plot(quotient_times,quotient, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot with two points (`quotient`) as shown above in my code.

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to kind of add more points to the above plot to make it have a trend like the following. Is it possible to do that?

[image]

For example, if we want to change the values of the `y-axis` we can do it easily as the following

```
factors = [100, 100, 100]
for (protname, values), m in zip(protocols.items(), factors):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.hist(values["quotient"], facecolor='blue', alpha=0.9, label=protname,align='left')
    y_vals = ax1.get_yticks()
    ax1.set_yticklabels(['{:3.0f}'.format(x * m) for x in y_vals])
    ax1.set_xlabel("Values")
    ax1.set_title(protname)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can call `plt.plot` multiple times to plot again on the same plot (add more values)

Comment: I have tried that but it keeps plotting them on the same point. I want the other points to be on a different `t` if you see the `x-axis` instead of at one.

Comment: if you plot the same data, it'll end up in the same place. Are you plotting different data each time?

Comment: No, I am plotting the same data.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following — in the second figure you provide, you have more points. Where would the locations of those points be coming from?

Comment: The second plot is using different data. I included that to explain more about my question.

Comment: That would be a useful thing to mention in your question. You need to explain what you want to accomplish "sort of have more points on the graph" isn't enough to work with to provide an answer.

Comment: Are you wanting to interpolate (add intermediate values to fill) the data maybe?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I wanted to do.

Comment: I've added an example using `np.interp`

Comment: Thank you but I would be grateful if you could try it with the data I included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add intermediate points to your data, you need to use some form of *interpolation*. In `numpy` there is `np.interp` which provides a simple interface for preforming linear interpolation.

The following is a simple example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3,10,20,30])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.plot(x, y, '.', ms=10)

# Create a continuous range for the x axis from first to last value
xc = np.arange(x[0], x[-1])
yi = np.interp(xc, x, y)

ax.plot(xc, yi, 'x', color='r')
```

This produces the following plot.

[image: interpolated data and original data]

The input data is shown as blue circles, the interpolated as red crosses.

The key thing to note is that to interpolate your data you need to first calculate the xaxis of the interpolated data (e.g. a regular range of values from min..max). Then you pass this new axis together with your current `x` and current `y` values to `np.interp`. The result is the new set of `y` values at the interpolated `x` locations.

Using your example data/script you can do —

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protocols = {}

types = {"data1": "data1_final.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] 
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }

    plt.figure(); plt.clf()

    plt.plot(quotient_times,quotient, ".", label=protname, color="blue")

    # Interpolate, along an axis from min..max quotient_times
    xc = np.arange(quotient_times[0], quotient_times[-1], 0.5)
    quotienti = np.interp(xc, quotient_times, quotient)

    plt.plot(xc, quotienti, 'x', color='r')    

    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot.

[image: interp with provided data]

Comment: @Brown I've downloaded your data + using your code I get a completely different plot. Can you double check it.

Comment: Really? Using the same code? I will double check it later. I am on train now and thank you and I will appreciate if you don't downvote it until I double check.

Comment: @Brown yep, same code. No problem, I'll check back later!

Comment: you are right, I shared a wrong data and I am sorry about that. I have updated with the correct data now and thank you so much.

Comment: @Brown if you need it tweaking at all just let me know, happy to help :)

Comment: Actually what i wanted is, if you see on the plot, we have two lines (one point at 0.8 and another point at about 0.5) and so i wanted to have the points to be interpolated around those similar to the second plot i uploaded for clarification. I would also appreciate if you can upvote my question :-) there are people who do nothing but downvote questions and i can't understand why.

Comment: Ah I get you, you would just need to interpolate those two sets of data seperately (separating using a threshold value). Unfortunately you can't interpolate the bottom line (as you can't interpolate from a single value).

Comment: @Brown Looking at it now :)

Comment: Thank you so much!